# Проблема с Lamp сервером: Could not open configuration file

Tags: apache, lamp, apache2, ubuntu

Конкретнее проблема с apache

```
:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restartapache2: Syntax error on line 210 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/macro.load: No such file or directoryAction 'configtest' failed.The Apache error log may have more information.   ...fail!
```

Как решить проблему?

p.s.**201 строка** Include mods-enabled/*.load

```
sudo ls /etc/apache2/mods-enabled alias.conf        autoindex.conf  macro.load    reqtimeout.loadalias.load        autoindex.load  mime.conf     setenvif.confauth_basic.load       cgi.load        mime.load     setenvif.loadauthn_file.load       deflate.conf    negotiation.conf  status.confauthz_default.load    deflate.load    negotiation.load  status.loadauthz_groupfile.load  dir.conf        php5.confauthz_host.load       dir.load        php5.loadauthz_user.load       env.load        reqtimeout.conf$ ls -l /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/итого 0...    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 28 мая    7 18:16 macro.load -> ../mods-available/macro.load (красная подсветка)...
```

после ввода

```
sudo rm /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/macro.load
```

красная подсветка предыдущего результата убраласьно появилась другая ошибка

```
~$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restartSyntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/conf.d/custom/vhosts:Invalid command '<Macro', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configurationAction 'configtest' failed.The Apache error log may have more information.   ...fail!
```

файл /etc/apache2/conf.d/custom/vhosts

```
<Macro VHost $host $path>    <VirtualHost *:80>        DocumentRoot "$path"        ServerAdmin vanya@localhost        ServerName $host        ServerAlias www.$host        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm index.shtml        <Directory "$path">        Options FollowSymLinks            Options all                AllowOverride All        </Directory>    </VirtualHost></Macro>Use VHost test.loc /home/www-data/www/test
```

Comment: Syntax error on line 210 of /etc/apache2/apache2.confСтроку 210 в студию.

Comment: немного поковырялся, понял что конфига нет вообще. продолжение, где мне скачать конфиг? LAMP сервер свежеустановленныйан...нет всётаки есть, сейчас посмотрю нужную строку210 строка Include mods-enabled/*.load

Comment: Как вариант переставить апач: sudo apt-get install --reinstall apache2 libapache2-mod-auth-mysql

Comment: $ ls -l /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/

Comment: также лог apache взглянуть бы.

Comment: lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 28 мая    7 18:16 macro.load -> ../mods-available/macro.load (красная подсветка)

Comment: символическая ссылка на macro.load. Вывод ls -l /etc/apache2/mods-available

Comment: Вывод ls -l /etc/apache2/mods-available. Если тут нет macro, можно попробовать его выгрузить , типа sudo a2dismod macro. Рестартнуть апач, если все гут, кривой модуль. Либо не полностью установился или не сконфигурирован. Можно установить мод отдельно, ща найду ссыль, скинуДополнение: Установка модуля отдельно$ sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-macro$ sudo a2enmod macro вот ссылка, тут подробней про данный модуль.http://www.linuxjournal.su/?p=1414#more-1414

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас симлинк /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/macro.load ссылается на несуществующий файл /etc/apache2/mods-available/macro.load

Сделайте:

```
sudo rm /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/macro.load
```

Comment: обновил вопрос. я так полагаю нужно заменить $host $path , но хочется в этом убедиться.

Comment: я подумал, что возможно LAMP не доустоновился, может есть пособ продолжить установку?

Comment: Командой sudo rm /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/macro.load, вы удалили мод macro. А в создании виртуал.хост вы его используете....<Macro VHost $host $path>    <VirtualHost *:80>        DocumentRoot "$path"        ServerAdmin vanya@localhost        ServerName $host        ServerAlias www.$host...Установите macro отдельно, ссылку выше я кидал, или исключите Macro из виртуал.хост

Comment: пример:#serv1<VirtualHost 127.0.0.2>ServerAdmin webmaster@serv1.ruServerName serv1DocumentRoot "g:/home/serv1/www"ScriptAlias /cgi/ "g:/home/serv1/cgi/"ErrorLog g:/home/serv1/error.logCustomLog g:/home/serv1/access.log common</VirtualHost>

Comment: сделал так:переустановил apache (командой выше)файл /etc/apache2/conf.d/custom/vhosts привёл к виду:<VirtualHost 127.0.0.2>ServerAdmin webmaster@serv1.ruServerName serv1DocumentRoot "/home/www-data/www"ScriptAlias /cgi/ "/home/www-data/cgi/"ErrorLog /home/www-data/error.logCustomLog /home/www-data/access.log common</VirtualHost>для танкистов открывать по адресу 127.0.0.2

Comment: ну так в итоге заработало?